# My windows 10 asus laptop won’t start up or reset. Not enough space on disk

Tags: windows-10, boot, reboot, asus-laptop

My asus rog laptop won’t start up, just goes to the blue screen with the many ways of repairing it. Tried everything including hard reset and safe mode and I keep getting the same error: not enough space on disk. I’m stuck in this. Any help?

Comment: Start with a bootable USB key and move documents, picture, videos and like onto a USB hard drive. Then run a fill disk cleanup, restart and try again

Comment: Can’t make a disk cleanup. I tried to do it through command prompt but it only shows me errors like: ... is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: You need to remove files and documents to make space to get started.

Comment: Ok got it. I’ll let u know if it worked when I find one usb

Comment: I posted an answer for you and perhaps you can accept that.

Comment: So now I have more space on the disk, it makes the hard reset with no problem, but when it comes to boot, it shows the same blue screen with the same error. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: You will need the Windows 10 ISO to initiate a fresh install.  Back up any documents first.

Answer (score 1):

You need to boot with a bootable USB Key and then you need to remove files and documents to make space to get started. That should allow you to get started.

Once started, if you continue to have issues, back up your data and initiate a fresh install.  The lack of disk space could have caused corruption of the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can boot from a Linux LiveUSB, mount the NTFS drive, and purge files which accumulate with use, but which you can run Windows without. More on those in a moment.

2) You can also, when you boot with a LiveUSB, move files from the NTFS drive onto a second USB drive, either a USB flash drive, external SSD, or external HDD.

To make the LiveUSB from another Windows PC:

Download Kubuntu's ISO file at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/19.10/release/kubuntu-19.10-desktop-amd64.iso

Next, check for download errors by https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0

Make a LiveUSB following these instructions on a Windows PC https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0

Once you make a LiveUSB, use your ASUS Laptop's boot menu and choose to boot from the LiveUSB. You will find the Kubuntu system pretty much Windows-like, but there's help at https://askubuntu.com and https://forum.kde.org if needed.

1) (continued) Erasable locations (substitute your user name in Windows for *YOURUSERNAME*):

```
  C:\Windows\Temp 
  C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\
  C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\CrashDumps\
  C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\CrashReports\
  C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache
  C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Code Cache\Js
  C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\cache\
  C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\LocalLow\Temp\
```

and I'm sure there are many, many more places to clean up.

==

Once you're back in Windows, take a look at https://www.itechtics.com/clear-types-windows-10-cache/ which offers even more ways to clean up your Windows files.